# How do I change my name in the age of social media?

Tags: awkward-situations

My parents invented a name and I have rolled with it well into my 20s. Althought it's made me into a person who I'm happy to be, I believe it is still very detrimental to my success and confidence.

I can think of two situations where it has done me more harm than help me:

- Resumes or dating apps where my name is a big presentational component. Having an unorthodox name can sometimes show that I was born in an uneducated minority.
- Having to spell my name at every party and not have an explanation or meaning for my name.

They're tiny issues but if it had been easy, I'd have changed my name long ago. I've moved cities a lot and have joined social circles numerous times. The only reason I haven't changed my name is that I am still using social media.

If my friends on social media see me go by another name, it will be a strong signal of low confidence. I know I'd think that of other people, and it's not something I want with my friends, with whom I've always tried to maintain a proud frame of myself.

Comment: Do you have a nickname that certain people (a new group of friends, colleagues, ...)  use to adress you? In most social network sites and even at my job it's possible to add a different name besides your official name that everyone can call you.

Comment: Could you please add your country or cultural area? I know of extremely few names that would indicate "that I was born in an uneducated minority" and it's not clear why changing your name would "be a strong signal of low confidence". Understanding the culture you're living in might help understanding your problem.

Comment: Is your goal to permanently change your name, not just in social media but entirely?

Comment: Have you tried using other "easier" name on social media or dating apps?

Comment: I've put this on hold as unclear. Could you please try to answer the questions people asked above, by [edit]ing the answers into your post? Also, I notice you haven't taken the [tour] yet. Doing so earns you a badge, so I can recommend it! If you're wondering what IPS is all about, we also have [help/on-topic] and a [faq](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3485/1599).